# How can I find files by content in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, qt, applescript

I want to find files at a given location whose content matches a given string. For example, there are a lot of files inside the desktop folder (or anywhere), like *.pdf, *.rtf, *.doc, *.txt, *.html and so on.

The user will be prompted to enter a string `thistext` and select the location `/Users/UserName/Desktop`. I want to get a list of the files from this location whose content contains `thistext`.

I found a command utility `mdfind`, but it returns the files whose name contains `thistext` as well. I don't want these files in the result list; I only want files whose content is `thistext`. I've used `grep`, but it's not working properly for me. Is there a way to customize `grep` or `mdfind` command to work for me?

Or if there is any AppleScript script available for performing such task?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some syntax errors in the above answer.
I just tested this in AppleScript, and it works for me in Yosemite 10.10.5:

```
set textToSearchFor to "YourTextHere"
set searchDir to "~/Documents/Test/"

set cmdStr to "mdfind 'kMDItemTextContent == \"*" & textToSearchFor & "*\"cd' -onlyin " & searchDir
set lstFiles to (do shell script cmdStr)
log lstFiles
```

Result:
`(*/Users/UserName/Documents/Test/PDF_Log.txt*)`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a query that only examines each file's text content, like so:

```
mdfind -onlyin ~/Desktop 'kMDItemTextContent == *thistext* cdw'
```

The `cdw` at the end of the query string means the comparison should ignore **c**ase, **d**iacritics, and **w**idth (which is mostly relevant for text with Asian characters).

Also, if you're doing this from an app, you shouldn't invoke the `mdfind` command as a subprocess. You should use the [`NSMetadataQuery`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMetadataQuery_Class/) class to do it within your app.

Comment: This command does nothing. It dont give any output. I cant use NSMetadataQuery because I am using Qt FrameWork.

Comment: Do you actually have text files on your desktop that contain "thistext"? I tested before posting and it works for me. I don't have experience with Qt, but surely it allows the use of native APIs, doesn't it? You're already building Mac-specific code even if you're just depending on `mdfind`. If the issue is that `NSMetadataQuery` is an Objective-C API, you could use [`MDQuery`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/MDQueryRef/), instead. It's a C API on which `NSMetadataQuery` is based.

Comment: Yes I did so. But cd ~/Desktop; grep -lr "thistext" * is working.

Comment: Have you disabled Spotlight or excluded the relevant directories from its indexing (for example, via the Privacy tab of System Preferences > Spotlight)?